# Calling Inkscape in Python

Tags: python, pdf, svg, inkscape

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

I am trying to convert SVG files to PDFs in Python. I want to use Inkscape for this. How can I call Inkscape in Python ?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Hi there. We like to see a bit of prior research before questions are asked here, and - ideally - a bit of code to go with the problem. I'd wager that "system command python" in a search engine would get you what you need.

Comment: sorry i am new with python ,i searched for 'svg to pdf in python ', but i couldn't find any answers.Anyway thanks for advice.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to communicate with the process at all, this should do just fine:

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.call(['program','arg1','arg2','arg3', ...])
```

Comment: what should i use for arguments?I mean , are the arguments becoming paths of svg files when i use inkspace ?

Comment: I try to use like `p = subprocess('/usr/bin/inkspace','file1.svg','file2.pdf')`  but it gives me an error like : `'module' pbject is not callable`

Comment: @user1351130 -- Try this:  `p=subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/inkscape','file1.svg','file2.pdf'])`

Comment: ok, thank you ,but i used this and it works to : `p=subprocess['/usr/bin/inkscape', 'file1.svg', '--export-pdf', 'file2.pdf']`

Comment: @medusalith: Look at Python's shlex.split() method.  It will split a single command string into proper arguments.

Comment: Using `/usr/bin/inkscape` is not portable; Python should already be aware of your `PATH` so use plain `inkscape` as the argument instead. If that doesn't work, it's safer to add `/usr/bin/` to your `PATH` then to force one location on all users.